# Should we make changes directly in Android external libraries?

Tags: android

I am using an external [library](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) in my Android project. So if i want to customize it according to my needs( color, layout), shall i make direct changes in the library or is it a bad practice to do so?

One other way would be to extend its classes and make changes in my project's code itself. So which is a better way. The first method is easier and i dont see any problem with that in future.

**The below code is just that SO is not letting me to submit the question without code**

The library that i am using provide some functions

```
public void setBackgroundResourceForDates(HashMap<Date, Integer> backgroundForDateMap);
public void setBackgroundResourceForDateTimes(HashMap<DateTime, Integer> backgroundForDateTimeMap);
public void setBackgroundResourceForDate(int backgroundRes, Date date);
public void setBackgroundResourceForDateTime(int backgroundRes, DateTime dateTime);
```

Comment: best thing to do is probably to extend the class you're using and override specific behaviour

Comment: It depends under what licence is the library available...

Comment: Why its best @thepoosh?

Comment: @Diffy, this way if there are fixes in an update, you will have no conflicts

Comment: But even if i am overriding a method that has been changed, then i will have to change my method @thepoosh

Comment: @Diffy - you still need to look at the changelogs and make sure that you don't need to change anything in your implementation